# Yellowness and Dim display on the Same Model Number of Lenovo

Tags: laptop, display, colors, lenovo-laptop, calibration

I recently purchased a Lenovo(IdeaPad 5 Pro 16ACH6) laptop and I have doubts that the laptop screen displays yellowness and dim hence I compared the same model number laptop then found a different display. The dealer said that each laptop is built with a different display panel of same model hence we face different display.

As I know and understand, the same model has completely copied the product.
So Can someone tell me that the dealer is right? Same Model Number laptop has a different display panel? or is it a manufacturing defect?

I took a BIOS photo of both laptops because there's no display setting issue. BIOS display shows default display hence showing original display of the both laptops.

[image: photo of both laptops in BIOS/UEFI]

Answer (score 0):

Looks within tolerance to me, for a laptop screen. Neither is great [though we can't tell how much your camera or profile changes in posting to the web have skewed what we can see here] Left is too warm but the right is actually too cool, making the 'incorrectness' appear larger. The only way to ensure colour accuracy between any two screens is to profile them with a hardware colorimeter.

The difference you're seeing is broadly known as a colour temperature difference. You may be able to swing it closer with the basic graphics controls. You could even swap between onboard profiles & see if there's one that makes you feel happier; this isn't going to improve accuracy, just user comfort.

BTW, comparing them before the graphics drivers & display profile has loaded means you are disabling any calibration/profile offset the manufacturer may have already applied to compensate for this.

Note also that laptops are generally shipped looking over 'punchy'. This makes them look more attractive on the showroom floor, again at sacrifice of accuracy. If you were to ever need to use this for colour reference work, the first thing to do is discard the manufacturer's profile & generate your own.

Comment: Thank @Tetsujin, First, In BIOS there's no setting effect by OS Profile or Graphic Setting. BIOS display default view. Second, Lenovo rejected compensation/replacement and said there's no issue. The company manufacturing it like that. My Simple Question is There's different display of Same Model Number of the laptops?

Comment: Of course there's no setting for colour profile. The drivers aren't even loaded yet. This is why it is not the right place to compare. It really doesn't matter whether the panels are the same, they *both* need correctly profiling. I have two monitors here, same manufacturer, same model, purchased at the same time. They look like yours at boot, one blue, one yellow - until the correct profiles load, then they look identical.

Comment: When give power supply to two same hardware product then they display different then I can't accept that those are same hardware because they should be on in default view,color and display. What if we use only DOS OS, Textmode and Command mode work. then? In that case, one device displays proper white and second display yellowness then what will you do for that?

Comment: If you have no calibration profile, then you'll just have to put up with it. The manufacturers will not take responsibility for small discrepancies which can easily be fixed in software, as part of a regular workflow. It is not, as I keep saying, important that the hardware is identical.

Comment: I am unable to understand  that when both hardware panels are the same and when providing power supply to them then they should display same color without yellowness and dim view.  I suppose that the calibration and profile settings enhance graphic display and improvement not effect RGB color

Comment: No two screens are the same. That's why we use calibration & profiling. No screen will provide any kind of colour reference without this. I'm really not sure how many different ways I can say the same thing.

Comment: Dear, Both attached snapshot Models have the same display panel and hardware so without any OS like window & Linux when we test panel by given power supply then default display should be same. Just Let me know how the company testing panels without any setting profile & calibration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136505/discussion-between-dev-d-and-tetsujin).